# How can I install GitExtensions in Mac OS?

Tags: git, macos, git-extensions

I use Mac OS High Sierra version 10.13.6

I want to install [GitExtensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions)

I read here : https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#installation-macos-2-5x-only

If I run : `mono GitExtensions.exe` in the terminal there exist error like this :

```
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Process 767 detached
(lldb) quit
Abort trap: 6
```

How can I solve the error?

**Update**

I get a solution, so I try change to be like this :

```
mono --arch=32 GitExtensions.exe
```

There is exist new error like this :

```
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
```

If I run `mono --version` in the terminal, the result like this :

[image]

How can I solve the new error?

Comment: What's your mono version?

Comment: @RussKie Mono JIT compiler version 5.14.0.177

Comment: There are better Git GUI clients that are macOS native applications. [Fork](https://git-fork.com) and [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) are two of the best.

Comment: @axiac Both Fork and SourceTree lack some features that only git-extension have. e.g they can't show diff of merge commit perfectly. Only GitExtension let me see diff of merge commit to both parent commits. Til now nothing can replace GitExtensions for me :(

Comment: I also miss the amazing blame & file history in GitExtensions which are integrated into one screen. SourceTree's implementation is pretty good though. Fork's is really lame.

Answer (score 5):

benhorgen's answer is not entirely wrong. While there *is* a mono version of Git Extensions (v2.51 line) that *does* run just fine on Linux, it was my experience that even this mono version of GitExt doesn't work correctly on Mac (app crashes). It may be possible to resolve these issues but I don't believe there is any quick-and-easy path to getting it working.

I had filed a [bug report](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/18330) with the mono team back in january and provided a good bit of technical detail. In that ticket,  sancheolz proposed a potential workaround involving editing and rebuilding mono from source that you might try. But I no longer have access to a Mac and am unable to test it. I would recommend to read that ticket and the setup instructions I had linked to there* and to try the proposed custom mono workaround. If successful, the mono team could make a patch upstream so that it is fixed for everyone. If not, providing additional info directly to the mono project team still seems like the best path toward a resolution.

* Direct link to install instructions I used: [here](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.51/getting_started.html#installation-macos-2-5x-only). Normally, I would include those details in my post as well but there is a fairly large amount of technical information in both that and the ticket that I can't adequately reduce/simplify for this post. I had also originally filed the bug report with the git extensions project [here](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/7578) and while the 2 issues are cross-linked, there may potentially be some small technical details that appear in one ticket but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the bad news, but GitExtentions is written for the Windows operating system. It will not run on MacOS.

I personally use SourceTree. I know others are fans of the GitHub app. And there is  Git integration in popular development environments like Eclipse and VS Code.